# Prove that if $P(a, b) = 1$ for any polynomial $P(a, b)$ with integer coefficients, then $\gcd(a, b) = 1$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, polynomials, integers, coprime

Let $P(a, b)$, be a polynomial with monomials all degree $1$ or higher and integer coefficients (in other words, there are no constant terms). Prove that if $P(a, b) = 1$ (when replacing $a$ and $b$ with integers), $a$ and $b$ are relatively prime. Thanks for help on proving this.

The converse of this (is easy to prove), If $a$ and $b$ are relatively prime, then there exists a function $f(a, b) = P(a, b)$ (where $P(a, b)$ is a polynomial) such that $f(a, b) = 1$. $P(a, b) = ax - by = 1$ where $x$ and $y$ are coefficients. (This comes from [Bézout's identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zout%27s_identity)).

Comment: if $(a,b)=d$ then $d|P(a,b)$

Comment: The title says `*any* polynomial` while the question asks `*a* polynomial`. You probably meant the latter, since the former can't be satisfied by any $a,b\,$, coprime or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assume $a$ and $b$ are not relatively prime, i.e., $\gcd(a,b)=d>1.$ Then $d$ must divide $P(a,b),$ since every term in the polynomial is either a multiple of $a$ or of $b.$ Thus, $P(a,b)\neq 1.$

Note that we can write $P(a,b)=a P_1(a,b)+b P_2(a,b)$ for integer polynomials $P_1$ and $P_2.$